# How to get the version of the TPM from UWP app

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Please tell me how to get the TPM version of the Lumia 950LX from UWP app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you please provide some more details as to what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Security/RequireRetrieveHealthCertificateOnBoot in the Policy CSP. If the device is enrolled and you are the MDM administrator this could serve as a proxy to determine if the device has TPM 2.0. You would have to be able to enroll the device for management.